# How to get the list of Wifi networks that you've connected

Tags: android

Is there any way to get the list of WiFi networks that you've connectedon your phone?

**Not the avaliable WiFi** the WiFi that you've entered the correct password and you've connection .

I've read about [`List<WifiConfiguration> getConfiguredNetworks ()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) but I've tried something like this :

```
public void ShowConfigWifi(Context context) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    List<WifiConfiguration> arraylist = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    Log.wtf(TAG, "Number of Networks" + arraylist.size());
}
```

But it returns me "4" when I only have configured 1 network on my device...

Comment: I'll test once agian to see if I misstyped something :P

Comment: I guess you're right tho, in a few days I'll test it and I'll let you know :D

Comment: I noticed it, you are amazing :D

Comment: @Yvette You'll be the best hehe :P, by the way I found also a post that I'm interesting to know because I did something like that guy and I ahd the same problem... [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944939/bluetooth-clossing-sockets-when-using-voice-recognition) is also for BT stuff, the thing is that I have a bt app that controls a robot and I wanted to put a voice recognition but when trying to do it the sockets closes and crashes :S