# Bluetooth clossing sockets when using voice recognition

Tags: android, sockets, android-fragments, bluetooth

I've implemented this [tutorial](https://wingoodharry.wordpress.com/2014/04/15/android-sendreceive-data-with-arduino-using-bluetooth-part-2/) on my APP, but I did many changes.... I've created a `TabLayout` so what I did (I don't think that's the good idea, well it is not since it doesn't work :)) on each fragment I copy pasted the code of the tutorial (I created the sockets to connect to my `Bluetooth`, I create connection to the device...) and when I tested it only with one `Activity` it worked well... but when I added the `TabLayout` it started to don't work. I think I could do all of the code of the `Bluetooth` on the `Activity` and then work with the objects of that `Activity` (from the `Fragment` I mean...) the problem is that on `onPause()` I have this :

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onPause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {

        }
}
```

And everytime I use this :

```
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, getString(R.string.VoiceControllerText));
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

It enters on `onPause()` and then the socket is closed, and I can't send info to `Bluetooth` I tried to comment that line `btSocket.close();` but the error says that `socket is closed`, I didn't commented the line of the other `Tab` (I only have 2) should I comment also the `socket.close()` of the other `Tab`?....

I'm looking for a solution that helps to me to implement / guide how to implement all of the code of `Bluetooth` as another class or something, that if I enter on the `onPause()` from one `Tab` the socket doesn't close..

And by the way I'm not sure that copying pasting the code of the `Bluetooth` (They are the same in one `Fragment` than the other....) it's a good idea... same `UUID` same all...

If you guys need more code to check it out, let me know and I'll post it.

Thanks.

### EDIT

First I have the first `Activity` which I sent to the `MainActivity` the `MAC address` as follows :

```
Intent i = new Intent(DeviceListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);
i.putExtra("name", name);
startActivity(i);
```

This is the most important code of my [`DeviceListActivity`](http://paste.ofcode.org/tFXEkCRkBdymK4v9WAMZhu)...

The second thing that I have is `MainActivity` but there I don't have anything about `Bluetooth` because I do stuff with it on `Fragments` inside of it...

I have this `Fragment` which works perfect (it's the first one) :

### Atributes

```
//Sending info
Handler bluetoothIn;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
final int handlerState = 0;                        //used to identify handler message
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
// SPP UUID service - this should work for most devices
private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
// String for MAC address
private static String address="";
```

in `onCreate()` I call this :

```
btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();// get Bluetooth adapter
    if (btAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.BtNotSupported), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
checkBTState();
```

I have the method to create the `socket`

```
private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
    return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
}
```

This is my `onResume()`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Get MAC del intent
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    address = intent.getStringExtra(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
    //Creates a device with the MAC from DeviceListActivity
    if(btAdapter!=null) {
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        try {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ShowSnack(getString(R.string.SocketCreationFailed), Color.RED);
        }
        //Trying to connect
        try {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
            }
        }
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
    }  
    else{
        ShowSnack(getString(R.string.toast_bt_unavailable), Color.RED);
    }
}
```

This is my `onPause()`

```
  @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try {
        //Close socket if leaves the Activity
        btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {

    }
}
```

And this is the method that I call to see if `Bluetooth` is enabled or not.

```
private void checkBTState() {

    if (btAdapter == null) {
        ShowSnack(getString(R.string.toast_bt_unavailable), Color.RED);
    } else {
        if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        } else {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `ConnectedThread` class to send and recieve stuff from `Bluetooth`.

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
 private final InputStream mmInStream;
 private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }
    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        int bytes;
        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);            //read bytes from input buffer
                String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Send stuff to Bluetooth
    public void write(char input) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Well and now, when I'm having problems is on the second `Fragment` where I have **THE SAME** code as here... that's why I guess that crashes when trying to use `Voice recognision`... when I try to send something to `Bluetooth`, well.. I'm sorry if that's too much code but that's the only thing that I have hope you understand my problem.

Comment: I don't have full visibility to code, so I cannot probably provide a solution, but when you start a new activity of course onPause is invoked and connection closed. In this sense I have two questions... first one is what happens in onResume method (if onPause closes connection, onResume should open it)? ... second one is what happens if you don't close connection in onPause... I mean, of course it should be closed somewhere but my I'm wondering if behavior when opening and closing the additional activity is correct...

Comment: @thetonrifles Do you need any code or something man? I can give you the code... I'll edit the question with onResume too.. but just tel me what you didn't understand and what you need the thing that I don't want is to create 2 bluetooths adapters and those stufs because since I created two fragments I have the same code on each Fragment and I don't like it...

Comment: @thetonrifles I've edited my code, now I think you'll be clear with your questions if you are not let me know and I'll explain you what you need, but I think the idea of [nick mosher](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35947494/4329781) is what I need but I need how to implement it correctly...

Comment: ok... I think I will be able to check everything this evening, together with the answer already provided.

Comment: @thetonrifles Just let me know when you are able to :)

Comment: I'm checking code, but I'm having some difficulties in understanding the overall flow you would like to get. I understand that you now have DeviceListActivity. From here you open MainActivity, that includes two fragments (with tabs). Which is purpose of the two fragments? As far as I understood you have one working good and the second one crashing. Sorry if I ask you again these things... but it's difficult for me to reproduce everything :)

Comment: Yes, because I have one tab that does some stuff and sends info to Bluetooth and the other tab does other stuff and ALSO send info to Bluetooth...

Comment: Ok, and as far as I understood both fragments use the same code but second one crashes. Of course it would be useful for me to see the stack trace of the crash. BTW In general if code is same it could be useful to implement a base fragment implementing shared code, or using a Service for handling communication with BT as suggested in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to implement it but I don't understand some stuff of that code... I need an inputstream and he didn't put and some things like write method... I would like to implement service one because it looks like a nice  solution I guess.... it crashes and says Socket close because when I use voice recognition it enters on onPause then it closes 1 socket I don't know if it's from first tab or second one but if I send stuff from the first tab it works perfect, if I go to the other tab press on voice recognition and go to first tab doesn't work neither

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106289/discussion-between-thetonrifles-and-androidwannabe).

Answer (score 2):

One problem that you're facing is that it seems that you're trying to manage the lifecycle of your Bluetooth connection all from within your activity. As you've seen, this can cause problems when the Activity's lifecycle functions (such as onPause() and onResume()) don't perfectly align with the lifetime of your connection. To solve this, you can create a Service that handles all of your connecting, sending and receiving, and disconnecting from that Bluetooth connection. The Service's lifetime is independent from the Activity, so even if your user is switching between Activities and Fragments, you can keep the Bluetooth connection open.

To set up your Service, make a new class that extends Service and put all of your Bluetooth handling objects in it.

```
public class BluetoothService extends Service {
    public static final String BLUETOOTH_SERIAL_UUID = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";
    private BluetoothSocket mSocket;
    private String mAddress = "bluetooth_mac_address_here";

    public void onCreate() {
        //Set up Bluetooth socket.
        BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mAddress);
            mSocket = btDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BLUETOOTH_SERIAL_UUID);
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            mSocket.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

This sets up the mSocket object when the Service is first launched. After that point, you'll be able to interact with the remote bluetooth device by simple calls to `mSocket.getInputStream()` and `mSocket.getOutputStream()` and reading/writing data using those. However, if you're not familiar with using Services, it can be a little confusing as to how to get your data from the Activity to and from the Service to transfer your data. Here's a way to do it using Intents.

Inside the same BluetoothService class, override `onStartCommand()`:

```
public class BluetoothService extends Service {
...
public static final String ACTION_SEND_DATA = "send_data";
public static final String ACTION_RECEIVED_DATA = "received_data";
public static final String EXTRA_BLUETOOTH_DATA = "bluetooth_data";

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //Register a BroadcastReceiver to handle "send" requests.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Parse your data to send from the intent.
            if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SEND_DATA)) {
                byte[] data = intent.getByteArrayExtra(EXTRA_BLUETOOTH_DATA);
                //Send the data over the Bluetooth Socket.
                try {
                    mSocket.getOutputStream().write(data);
                } catch(IOException ioe) {
                    //This might happen if you try to write to a closed connection.
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

This will give you a way to use Intents to send your data from an Activity to the Service, but not yet to receive that data. I'll get to that later. Note that I've used `LocalBroadcastReceiver` to register the intent. This means that the `BroadcastReceiver` that we register will only be given intents that were both broadcast from within your app and have a matching action. I just used that to simplify the intent interactions, but in the future if you want to allow external apps to send data using your service (probably unlikely), then you'll need to change that. Anyway, from your Activity, do the following to send the data through your Service:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        String myString = "This is some data I want to send!";
        //Create an intent with action saying to send data
        //with the byte[] of data you want to send as an extra.
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(BluetoothService.ACTION_SEND_DATA);
        sendIntent.putExtra(BluetoothService.EXTRA_BLUETOOTH_DATA, myString.getBytes());
        //Sends the intent to any BroadcastReceivers that have registered receivers for its action.
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I have class in a few minutes and can't finish this post right now, but I'll be on in a few hours to cover how to set up the receiving part. In the meantime, feel free to check out [this code](https://github.com/nicholastmosher/easycom-core/blob/master/connection/ConnectionService.java#L670) from a project of mine that solves exactly these problems. Look at the TransferManager class and how it uses Threads to provide a non-blocking way to receive data from the InputStream of the BluetoothSocket.

==========================================================================

Ok, now let's look at how you can use your Service to receive data from your remote Bluetooth device. One thing to know about Services is that they are not run on separate threads from your Activities. While they maintain their state and their lifecycle functions are decoupled from those of Activities, they are still both executed on the main UI thread. This means that if you put code in your Service that is slow or blocking, it will respectively slow down or freeze your Activity's UI. This is behavior that we definitely want to avoid, so when we consider receiving data from a Bluetooth device (a blocking operation), we need to handle that operation by creating a new Thread within the custom Service class. Let's define a custom class that extends Thread as an inner class of our BluetoothService:

```
public class BluetoothService extends Service {
    ...
    public void onCreate() {...}
    public int onStartCommand(...) {...}

    public static class ReceiveThread extends Thread {
        private boolean isRunning;
        private InputStream mBluetoothInputStream;

        public ReceiveThread(InputStream bluetoothInputStream) {
            mBluetoothInputStream = bluetoothInputStream;
            isRunning = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(mBluetoothInputStream));
            String line;
            while(isRunning) {
                try {
                    //This is the line that blocks until a newline is read in.
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                } catch(IOException ioe) {
                    //This happens if the InputStream is closed.
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                    //Stop the thread from looping.
                    isRunning = false;
                }

                //Make sure our line in isn't null or blank.
                if(line == null || line.equals("") {
                    continue; //Start again at top of while loop.
                }

                //Notify your Activity about the new data.
                Intent receivedIntent = new Intent(BluetoothService.this, MyActivity.class);
                receivedIntent.setAction(ACTION_RECEIVED_DATA);
                receivedIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_BLUETOOTH_DATA);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(BluetoothService.this).sendBroadcast(receivedIntent);

                try {
                    //This is an arbitrary sleep time just to prevent
                    //this from looping without any restriction.
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    //This happens if the Thread is interrupted for any reason.
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    isRunning = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, now you can spin up a new ReceiveThread by throwing a few lines onto the end of `onStartCommand()` in the Service:

```
ReceiveThread receiver = new ReceiveThread(mSocket.getInputStream());
receiver.start();
```

The last step is to actually get that data into your Activity. To do that, you'll create a BroadcastReceiver that listens for the broadcasts sent out by the ReceiveThread. In your Activity class, put this at the end of `onCreate()`:

```
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Get your data out of the intent.
            byte[] data = intent.getByteArrayExtra(BluetoothService.EXTRA_BLUETOOTH_DATA);
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(BluetoothService.ACTION_RECEIVED_DATA));
}
```

The `onReceive()` method gets called every time your BluetoothService's ReceiveThread reads a new line from your remote bluetooth device. Depending on your actual application, this may or may not be suitable for you (for example, if your program isn't text/command based and has no newline characters in it). You can change that behavior by swapping out the BufferedReader in the ReceiveThread with another type of Reader.

**EDIT:**

In your snippet you've built a stub method called `write` that you seem to be fixated on having. Having a method like this would require you to execute it as a direct call from the Activity, which isn't what you want. If you look up in this post, you'll see that I've put some code that was meant to be called from your Activity which uses intents to deliver your data to the Service to be written. Look at the snippet beginning with `public class MyActivity extends Activity`. The point of using intents is that the Android framework will take care of carrying the "extra" data over to the Service, which is then unpackaged in the `onReceive()` method in `onStartCommand()` in the Service, where you can see the OutputStream is being written to.

The only other thing is that I did forget the `return Service.START_STICKY` for the `onStartCommand()` method of the Service. Everywhere you would want to put that `write` method that you made in your snippet, put the code about creating and sending the Intent using the LocalBroadcastManager.

Comment: I've implemented your code, but I mostly need the write method since I'm not using the write method (at the moment) ... Is the method that I need to send chars to the Bluetooth device, do you have TeamViewer or something so I can show you what I have? Is not that much it's only 2 Fragments

Comment: It would be preferable if you could post  the code you're using as an edit to your original post, as well as exactly what you're trying to accomplish and the problems you're facing. That way others who might be having the same problem as you can use this post as a reference.

Comment: I just edited my question... hope you understand now what's the problem on there.... and thanks for your perfect answer... trying to implement it still in my code but wanted to make sure that you know what's happening on my app

Comment: @AndroidWannabe it looks like you are creating and starting a new ConnectedThread each time that onResume() runs, which can be many times. Is this onResume() method in your Activity or your Fragment? Also, have you tried making an example Service like the code I posted above?

Comment: Yes, I'm creating a new ConnectedThread each time... that's why I wanted to know how to create a service like you said... but implementing it I faced with some problems... could you rewrite your answer knowing my code now please? Where do I have to put the write method to send to Bluetooth? Shall I have to create a SP to store the MAC address ?

Comment: You can post an answer tomorrow if you want... not meaning that you have to do it today man..

Comment: You got it @Nick Mosher?What's the problem now?

Comment: I added this Service but I commented the lines that it give to me errors, and also what I need to implement [code](http://paste.ofcode.org/NR5CFsxiPvNhGVC32fhKEa), I actually need an outPutStream to send info like my ConnectionThread could you check this?

Comment: So I don't need outputStream? I don't get it what you said to me about write method... I mean I have to put the snipped of my write in the BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: I've you've implemented all of the code in the `Service` class how I put it, then to send data from your Activity to your remote device, do: `Intent sendIntent = new Intent(BluetoothService.ACTION_SEND_DATA);
        sendIntent.putExtra(BluetoothService.EXTRA_BLUETOOTH_DATA, "String data to send".getBytes()); LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);`

Comment: With the same code of your Answer if I do this Intent it will send stuff?

Comment: Nick can't make the project work, can you just explain me how to implement the write method, take a look at my edit please.

Comment: Nick please, can you take a little time to explain why my code doesn't work? I tested what you've said to me... but I need a big example I guess...

Comment: I've recently put out a release of my Android library that simplifies the process for connecting to Bluetooth devices. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/nicholastmosher/easycom-core). I can't guarantee that it will be perfectly stable since it's very new, but it may accomplish what you need done.

Comment: I'll be able to "send info by voice"? I mean I had the problem that when I leave the Activity it was calling onResume and in on my Resume I was clossing the sockets so that's why it crashed... your library is done with Services, etc?

Comment: By the way, is this Library free to use?

Comment: Yep, the library uses services and also handles multi-threading, so even if you open more than one connection they won't block each other or the UI. The library is licensed under GPL 3.0, so you can use it as long as it remains open source. I don't know the nature of your project, but it can't be used in anything proprietary.